# android handle progress dialog in a separate async task class

Tags: android, android-asynctask, progressdialog

This is my MainActivity, i want handle progress dialog in the AsyncTask class, but passing the context to the asyncTask seems not working and the application crash with NullPointerException error, if i try to set the progressDialog in MainActivity, and then get reference to it in AsyncTask with mContext.progress, application crash with WindowLeaked error.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity{

ConnectionHandler ch;
SearchForCard mTask = null;
String finalUrl = "";
Button searchBtn;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ch = new ConnectionHandler(this);

    searchBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
                mTask = ch.new SearchForCard();
                mTask.execute(finalUrl);
            }

        }
    });

}
```

in my ConnectionHandler class i want create separate asynctask for every thing i have to do, pls dont provide solution for inner Asynctask in MainActivity, it's not what i want to do

```
public class ConnectionHandler{

private MainActivity mContext;
Handler mHandler = new Handler();
Document doc = null;
Elements title = null;
String response = null;
ProgressDialog progress;

public ConnectionHandler(MainActivity ctx)
{
    mContext = ctx;

    progress = new ProgressDialog(mContext); <--APPLICATION CRASH HERE WITH DEBUGGER
    progress.setTitle("loading");
    progress.setIndeterminate(false);

}

public class SearchForCard extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {


    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {

        progress.show();

        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(String... url) {

        try{
            doc = Jsoup.connect(url[0]).get();
            Log.d("RESPONSE",doc.toString());
        } catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return false;
    }

     @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {

            super.onPostExecute(result);

            progress.dismiss();

        }
}
}
```

What i'm doing wrong? Thanks

This is the error:

```
02-08 12:40:28.275: E/WindowManager(3574): Activity com.pagiodevelop.MainActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@5371c7b4 that was originally added here
02-08 12:40:28.275: E/WindowManager(3574): android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.pagiodevelop.MainActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@5371c7b4 that was originally added here
02-08 12:40:28.275: E/WindowManager(3574):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:374)
02-08 12:40:28.275: E/WindowManager(3574):  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:292)
02-08 12:40:28.275: E/WindowManager(3574):  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:224)
02-08 12:40:28.275: E/WindowManager(3574):  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl$CompatModeWrapper.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:149)
02-08 12:40:28.275: E/WindowManager(3574):  at android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.addView(Window.java:547)
02-08 12:40:28.275: E/WindowManager(3574):  at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:277)
02-08 12:40:28.275: E/WindowManager(3574):  at com.pagiodevelop.ConnectionHandler$SearchForCard.onPreExecute(ConnectionHandler.java:40)
02-08 12:40:28.275: E/WindowManager(3574):  at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:586)
02-08 12:40:28.275: E/WindowManager(3574):  at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:534)
02-08 12:40:28.275: E/WindowManager(3574):  at com.pagiodevelop.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:50)
02-08 12:40:28.275: E/WindowManager(3574):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4084)
02-08 12:40:28.275: E/WindowManager(3574):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:16966)
02-08 12:40:28.275: E/WindowManager(3574):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
02-08 12:40:28.275: E/WindowManager(3574):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
02-08 12:40:28.275: E/WindowManager(3574):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-08 12:40:28.275: E/WindowManager(3574):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
02-08 12:40:28.275: E/WindowManager(3574):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-08 12:40:28.275: E/WindowManager(3574):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-08 12:40:28.275: E/WindowManager(3574):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
02-08 12:40:28.275: E/WindowManager(3574):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
02-08 12:40:28.275: E/WindowManager(3574):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: How & where you instantiate your progress dialog?

Comment: call  ch = new ConnectionHandler(this); in onCreate(), not before that

Comment: try getapplicationcontext(); method

Comment: user i have edited like you said, but i get WindowLeaked error, i will add the error code now

Comment: @Mat did you manage to fix the error ?

Comment: @gaurav4sarma i added the answer below ;), let me know if it works for you

Comment: Thank you @Mat for the reply. I have solved it some other way but i am sure it can be done like the way you mentioned below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be the correct solution when using progress dialog and async task

```
public static class SearchForCard extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {

    private Context mContext;
    private ProgressDialog mProgress;

    public SearchForCard (Context context) {
        mContext = context;
    } 

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        mProgress = new ProgressDialog(mContext);
        //customize the progress dialog here
        mProgress.setCancelable(false);
        mProgress.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(String... url) {
        //do your background work and return something
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
        if (mProgress != null && mProgress.isShowing())
            mProgress.dismiss();

        //evaluate result
    }
}
```